# What function to use to show 2 images when you pass your mouse over it?

Tags: javascript, html, mouseover, rollover

I'm trying to make my header looks like this:  http://wareztuga.ws/index.php and i was wondering how they managed to do that when we pass over the home bottum it flashes.

I know we need to have two images for that result but i need the funcion.

Comment: Dunno what's their exact code, but what you're after is called "image rollover" - just Google it for tons of functions. I recommend using jQuery for this as it's the most powerful and simple to use. Here is one for example that look good: http://www.selfcontained.us/2008/03/08/simple-jquery-image-rollover-script/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many approaches to implementing an image rollover.  Here's a very basic approach:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>rollover demo</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function swap(element, image) {
      element.src = image;
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="home_normal.png" onmouseover="swap(this, 'home_rollover.png');" onmouseout="swap(this, 'home_normal.png');"/>
  <img src="about_normal.png" onmouseover="swap(this, 'about_rollover.png');" onmouseout="swap(this, 'about_normal.png');"/>
</body>
</html>
```

A more preferable method would be to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com) or some other library that keeps the HTML free of JavaScript code.  You'll find many, many different ways to do it if you Google "javascript image rollover" or "jquery image rollover".

Comment: I have a doubt. What do we change in the javascript funcion so we can get too images? Can you edit your code so i can see it? Sorry for this mess  :D

Comment: Sure.  I edited my answer to make the code more generic and used two img tags as an example.

Comment: ah this is good the code is more simple. I noticed than in the other code we had to make a script for each image but now this is away more simple. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

this is not related to PHP. you just change the image-src ... there are many code-examples for that out there. here is [one](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tutorials/javascript/javascript_image_change_functions.php3).

Comment: hey can you explain me what does that funcion do? Which language is it?